# Попросить доступ к камере (не в начале игры)

Tags: android, unity3d, unity3d-android

При загрузке игры, приложения запрашивает разрешения на камеру (в игре используеться), но это включаеться только в настройках, можно ли запросить доступ тогда, когда он сделает определенные действия для её включения?

Comment: неужто мой ответ не помог?

Comment: ой, да я с праздниками и совсем забыл об этом, конечно помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я таким не занимался сам, но на сколько я понимаю тебе нужно оверрайдить AndroidManifest вручную что бы оно не запрашивало "лишних" пермишнов

https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/android-manifest.html

Или вообще отключить их на запуске:

```
 <meta-data
     android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog"
     android:value="true"
     />
```

А потом уже идти по мануалу для реквеста пермишнов во время рантайма по примеру из оф.документации: https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/Manual/android-RequestingPermissions.html